# When does the forest FINALLY end?

Tags: candy-box-2

I've been in this quest for two days and have 1,085,600 candies but I can't reach the end! I don't know what to do.

Comment: Are you stuck at the right end of the forest, then?

Answer (score 2):

Thing is, It keeps spawning wolves until you reach the end.

**I'm guessing** you have the octopus's crown with obsidian, so it sometimes spawns octopuses in front of you so you cannot move.

#### SOLUTION:

Either just take off your crown or get another one and enchant it with jaspers.

If I'm wrong, please provide a screenshot of how you're stuck (There are multiple ways of getting stuck).